# ADFS 2.0 Overcome Splash page

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs2.0

I'm using ADFS 2.0 under Active Directory. Everything works fine but I would like to get rid of the initial page that contains a drop down list and instead, have a direct link for the user to access the service provider directly. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is officially called the Home Realm Discovery (HRD) page.

Yes - you can customize it:

- [AD FS 2.0 Sign-In Pages Customization Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895356.aspx)
- [Automating Home Realm Discovery (HRD)](http://bennykmathew.wordpress.com/2012/11/25/automatedhrhrd/)